# Converting String to Array and back in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I simply have a huge array in a string like this:

`"test", "blabla", "anothertest", "et", "cetera"`

I need to be able to convert it to an array, preferable without the " "'s still left over.
I have no idea how javascript would be able to do this, but I heard JSON was able to do something like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON is fine indeed:

```
var string = '"test", "blabla", "anothertest", "et", "cetera"';
JSON.parse('[' + string + ']');
```

Keep in mind that `string` must respect the JSON syntax. More precisely, you have to check that double quotes are used, the separator is a comma and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If your string contains data in quotes, and separated with comma, it almost valid json. Just do this

```
var myparsedarray = JSON.parse("[" + yourstring + "]");
```